# SQL SERVER FileTable/FILESTREAM share suddenly becomes unavailable

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, troubleshooting, filetable

We had difficulty setting up a FileTable share on a SQL 2014 instance and after giving up on trying to name it after our instance name, we left the name of the share as mssqlserver, but it finally came online, online meaning if you right click in SSMS on the FileTable table you can "Explore FileTable Directory", however it seems to randomly go offline again after some time and you receive the usual canned error message:
[image]

So, after magically disabling/enabling FILESTREAM at the server level, database level via t-sql/ssms/configuration manager it some how comes back, but I have to mess with the setting at all of those spots for it to come back! and there seems to be no magical sequence of steps that makes it come back.

Has anyone out there experienced this? Will a restart of the service/server help this? If not, will a repair of sql server help?

Comment: So you're using FileTables? Or classic Filestream..? Can you access the filestream share using the UNC path when the GUI is throwing this error msg?

Comment: Yes, sorry, FileTables! No I cannot reach the UNC path when the GUI is throwing the error, however I CAN reach it when I am local to the box via SSMS or UNC. I am one restart away from calling microsoft css support team.

Comment: I'm trying to replicate your error... Just checking that non-transaction access is enabled for filestream in your setup? Also that your filestream config is set to allow remote connections in sql server configuration manager?

Comment: yes and yes, and after we rebooted the entire server, the filetable broke and we had to perform the magic to get it back, so we will be getting in touch with MS

Comment: the server restart broke the filetable share as expected... phoning MS now.

Comment: This just happened to us. Did MS provide a fix? In order to make it work on our server, I had to renamed the share on the service properties from mssqlserver to mssqlserver1.

Comment: @EricSwiggum This is currently happening to me as well. Any fix?

Comment: I never phone MS, and basically if i turn off FS completely in SSMS on the server properties and re-enable it, that would "fix" the issue... not sure if any of use want to eat $500 or more to find out why. I guess I could submit something to MS connect. However, i will add that it hasn't acted up in some time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be related to [KB4492899 - FIX: FileTable database level directory is inaccessible after database startup in SQL Server 2016 and 2017](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4492899-fix-filetable-database-level-directory-is-inaccessible-after-database-startup-in-sql-server-2016-and-2017-c9e8d26d-ffda-2ee9-ffe9-1cc700c35206).

SQL Server 2014 (and possibly earlier additions) also appear to be affected and don't appear to have a fix, although the workaround should still work.

The given workaround requires all existing connections to be closed.

Here are the contents of the KB article, just in case the link is broken in the future:

**Symptoms**

During Microsoft SQL Server 2016 and 2017 startup, if a user tries to connect to a database before it is started, the user session may cause the database to be auto-started. When this occurs, if the database contains a FileTable and has FILESTREAM non_transacted_access enabled, then the database-level FileTable directory is inaccessible after database startup. If you try to access the folder through File Explorer, it may indicate that the folder is unavailable. When you run a "dir" command from Command prompt, it returns "The system cannot find the file specified."

Additionally, you may see the following errors in the error log that indicate a user session triggered the database to auto-start:

- DateTime Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
- DateTime Logon       Login failed for user 'UserName'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'DatabaseName'. [CLIENT: IPNumber]

**Status**

Microsoft has confirmed that this is a problem in the Microsoft products that are listed in the "Applies to" section.

**Resolution**

This issue is fixed in the following cumulative updates for SQL Server:

Cumulative Update 15 for SQL Server 2017

Cumulative Update 6 for SQL Server 2016 SP2

About cumulative updates for SQL Server:

Each new cumulative update for SQL Server contains all the hotfixes and all the security fixes that were included with the previous cumulative update. Check out the latest cumulative updates for SQL Server:

Latest cumulative update for SQL Server 2017

Latest cumulative update for SQL Server 2016

**Workaround**

The workaround for this issue is to disable and re-enable the FILESTREAM non_transacted_access of the database.

```
ALTER DATABASE [DatabaseName] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

ALTER DATABASE [DatabaseName] SET FILESTREAM ( NON_TRANSACTED_ACCESS = OFF )

ALTER DATABASE [DatabaseName] SET FILESTREAM ( NON_TRANSACTED_ACCESS = FULL )

ALTER DATABASE [DatabaseName] SET MULTI_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

Comment: Extremely helpful

Answer (score 1):

It appears that after setting it via configuration manager the issue went away.

Comment: I'll consider this issue ... "resolved" as it appears to no longer be happening although I never really got any real explanation as to why.